# Xcode's .pbxproj file parsing error after merging

Tags: ios, xcode

I merge one branch to another and when I run `pod install`, I get following error:

```
Nanaimo::Reader::ParseError - [!] Dictionary missing ';' after key-value pair for "objects", found ""
#  -------------------------------------------
#   rootObject = FC0C89D3193D83EB00EB8EA8 /* Project object */;
#  }
6905>  
   ^
#  -------------------------------------------
```

And also, my Xcode project is not opened showing `No scheme`. I cannot do something there. It seems I don't have references of some files after merging. Also, I don't have that files in `Compile Sources`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you had a merge conflict.

The surest way of solving your problem is to revert `YourProject.xcodeproj/YourProject.pbxproj` to the last known-good version.

Once you've done that, you can add any missing files back using Xcode.

The Xcode project file is a horrible source of merge conflicts; it always pays to be very careful when merging or rebasing.

Comment: Or they could open the `.pbxproj` file using an editor like VS Code, and resolve the merge conflicts, assuming that is the problem

Comment: They absolutely could. It's not a fun task, however. As long as there aren't too many files to add back in after the revert, it's probably quickest to do it the way I've described.

Comment: True. Your way is better if they don't know how to fix merge conflicts in the `.pbxproj` file. A bit cumbersome, but definitely safer

Comment: I tried like that. But after reverting to previous state, I can't add such a group. Because Xcode telling my that it can't create it with that name. I think it knows about it and sees it as a duplicate folder.